# What is wrong with this Google Scripts code regarding last modified date for Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, datetime, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a complete beginner and just trying to make an interface that the rest of my family can use for budgeting. The only thing I am struggling with is the automation of the last modified date for certain cells. Whenever I run the code as an add-on it only modifies column 7 as specified in the first statement even if I enter the code into column 10,11,15,etc. seemingly ignoring the other “else if” statements.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  
  if(col === 5,6 && row > 3 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "2021" ){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,7).setValue(new Date());
  } 
  else if(col === 10,11 && row > 3 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "2021" ){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,12).setValue(new Date());
  } 
  else if(col === 15,16 && row > 3 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "2021" ){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,17).setValue(new Date());
  } 
  else if(col === 20,21 && row > 3 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "2021" ){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,22).setValue(new Date());
  } 
  else if(col === 25,26 && row > 3 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "2021" ){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,27).setValue(new Date());
  } 
  else if(col === 30,31 && row > 3 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "2021" ){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,32).setValue(new Date());
  } 
  else if(col === 35,36 && row > 3 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "2021" ){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,37).setValue(new Date());
  } 
  else if(col === 40,41 && row > 3 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "2021" ){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,42).setValue(new Date());
  } 
  else if(col === 45,46 && row > 3 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "2021" ){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,47).setValue(new Date());
  } 
  else if(col === 50,51 && row > 3 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "2021" ){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,52).setValue(new Date());
  } 
  else if(col === 55,56 && row > 3 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "2021" ){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,57).setValue(new Date());
  } 
  else if(col === 60,61 && row > 3 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "2021" ){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,62).setValue(new Date());
  } 
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised that it even does something, because `col === 5,6` surely doesn't do what you expect it to do. Maybe you meant `(col ===5 || col === 6)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const cA1 = [5,6,10,11,15,16,20,21,25,26,30,31,35,36,40,41,45,46,50,51,55,56,60,61]
  const cA2 = [7,7,12,12,17,17,22,22,27,27,32,32,37,37,42,42,47,47,52,52,57,57,62,62]
  const idx = cA1.indexOf(e.range.columnStart);
  if( sh.getName() == "2021" && e.range.rowStart>3 && ~idx ) {
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, cA2[idx] ).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I don’t really understand it but it worked!!

Comment: I don't really understand it either.  I just tried to figure what you were trying to do.  You might want take a look at [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) it's a bit cryptic I admit but I think you were thinking in means `or` but it doesn't.  onEdit trigger function can be difficult to get working.  You can run them if you provide the event object  by running from another function.  But I usually run them by editing the sheet and using Spreadsheet.toast() and writing the eventlog out into one of the cells .

Comment: The [~](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT) is an interesting operator to learn  because a lot of times I want to get the index with the indexOf() and check the logic at the same time but I don't want to  run the `indexOf()` method twice because onEdit  simple triggered functions must complete in 30 seconds or less so every function call counts against you.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( col === 5,6 ) {
    ...
}
```

is equivalent to

```
if ( 6 ) {
    ...
}
```

where the if statement is always true as `6` is a truthy value

```js
var col = 1; // Let's take 1 for example

if ( col === 5,6 ) {
  console.log( 'Matches first if condition' );
}

if ( 6 ) {
  console.log( 'Matches second if condition' );
}

if ( col === 5 ) {
  console.log( 'Matches third if condition' );
}
```

To check if the given number is in a list of numbers, you can either:

1. Compare them separately

```
if ( ( col === 5 || col === 6 ) && /* the rest of your logic here */ ) {
    ...
}
```

2. Put the numbers into an `Array` and find the matching number with `indexOf` so that you can add more column numbers you want to match easily in the future

```
if ( [ 5, 6 ].indexOf( col ) !== -1 && /* the rest of your logic here */ ) {
    ...
}
```

Also, you do not have to do `row > 3 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "2021"` checks in every `if` statements. Check it once and proceed to check for matching columns

```
var row         = e.range.getRow();
var col         = e.range.getColumn();
var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
var currentDate = new Date();

if ( row > 3 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "2021" ) {
    if ( col === 5 || col === 6 ) {
        activeSheet.getRange( row, 7 ).setValue( currentDate );
    }

    if ( col === 10 || col === 11 ) {
        activeSheet.getRange( row, 12 ).setValue( currentDate );
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another way to shorten your code and remove repetitive strings

```
function onEdit(e) {
      var row = e.range.getRow(),
          col = e.range.getColumn(),
          arrOfCols = [5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60];
    
      if (row > 3 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "2021") {
        if (arrOfCols.indexOf(col)>-1) e.range.offset(0,2).setValue(new Date());   
        if (arrOfCols.indexOf(col-1)>-1) e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date())
      }
    }
```

`if (arrOfCols.indexOf(col)>-1)` - this condition will check if the current column is in the list of `arrOfCols` columns (5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60) - if **yes**, then offset two columns to the right and write the timeshtamp `e.range.offset(0,2).setValue(new Date())`

'if (arrOfCols.indexOf(col-1)>-1)' - this condition will check if the current column is in the list of `arrOfCols` columns (6,11,16,21,26,31,36,41,46,51,56,61) - if **yes**, then offset one column to the right and write the timeshtamp `e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date())`

Comment: Another way is to use a loop `for (let i=5; i<65; i+=5)` then use `i`, `i+1` and `i+2` for the other values.